# The value for the useBean class attribute logbean.LoginBean is invalid

Tags: java, html, jsp, javabeans

I have the following code, which when I run on my TOMCAT server, gives me the error: jspbeanlogin/loginbean.jsp (line: 7, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute logbean.LoginBean is invalid.  What am I doing wrong, I don't know. Can someone explain what can I possibly be missing. Thank you. :-)

```
<HTML>   
<HEAD><TITLE>DataBase Search</TITLE></HEAD>  
<BODY>

<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>  

<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean" >

<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<

%=request.getParameter(\"userName\")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<

%=request.getParameter(\"password\")%>"/>

  </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:forward page="hello">
<jsp:param name="username" value="<%=db.getUserName()%>" />
<jsp:param name="password" value="<%=db.getPassword()%>" />

</jsp:forward> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct this line for property `userName`

```
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter(\"username\")%>"/>
```

the value comes from this line

```
<jsp:param name="username" value="<%=db.getUserName()%>" />
```

refer this link it i feel it explains a similar problem [JavaBean 'value for the useBean class attribute classes.UserData is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933320/javabean-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-classes-userdata-is-invalid)

Comment: I have followed those steps on the links and still the same error annoys me. I know where the errors are, but I still dont know how to correct them

Comment: is the page you are forwarding to a jsp or html. i am not seeing any extesion