# Bean and jsp : classes.UserData is invalid

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have read severals threads about the following exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /savename.jsp(1,1) The value for the useBean class attribute UserData is invalid.
```

I Saw :

[JavaBean 'value for the useBean class attribute classes.UserData is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933320/javabean-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-classes-userdata-is-invalid?rq=1)

[The value for the useBean class attribute ... is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

So i have :

1. My Bean have constructor with no args, setter and getter.
2. My .class is in the myApp/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/
3. I have those lines in my jsp using my bean :

What am i missing here ? i already did all the requierements.

See also my beans code :

```
package user;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Serializable;



public class UserData implements Serializable{

    private String user;
    private String mail;
    private String age;

    public UserData(){
    }

    public void setUser(String user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail){
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public void setAge(String age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public String getMail(){
        return mail;
    }

    public String getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your JSP to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing tomcat again solved the problem. I still don't know what was going on.